# create a dropdown with links in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, combobox, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with records that include a client name, and multiple links to their associated projects.

If I were using excel, I would create comboboxes that pop up when you click their "links" attribute, and then you could click the links from inside that combobox.

However, google apps script doesn't support comboboxes.

An alternative I thought of was creating dropdowns that contain the links, but this does not work, either.

Is there any way I can get a similar functionality from a google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would use UiApp.createApplication() and SpreadsheetApp.getUi() to
   create a sidebar.
2. I would create two list boxes and two buttons.

The first list/button pair:

- List would dynamically list the names of all clients.
- Button has clickHandler that creates a list item (.createListItem())
  per link for the chosen client.

The second list/button pair:

- List of all links for the client chosen by first list.
- Button opens new tab at link URL.

(Second button could be replaced with onChange event handler attached to second .listBox())

Hope this helps!

Comment: Marking this as accepted, I hadn't even been exposed to the UiApp class before this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it yet, but I think you would use DataValidation to create the drop-down.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation